# Resolving NodeJS CSS subpackages?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, postcss, postcss-import

I'm creating a [CSS library](https://github.com/superflycss/superflycss) and I'd like to support subpackages the same way RxJS does.  For example with RxJS we can import the entire kitchen sink like this (Taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs):

```
var Rx = require('rxjs/Rx'); 
Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3); // etc
```

Or individual operators like this:

```
var Observable = require('rxjs/Observable').Observable;
// patch Observable with appropriate methods
require('rxjs/add/observable/of');
require('rxjs/add/operator/map');
```

My initial observation is that this may be as simple as just packaging the modules in subfolders of the root module.  For example [RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) `node_modules` install folder has the subfolder `rxjs/add/observable` which contains all the observable extensions like `zip.js, throw.js...`, etc.

So following this pattern [postcss-import](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import) could be extended to resolve imports in submodule folders the same way.  For example:

- `@import @superflycss/utilities-layout/margins`

Would import `node_modules/superflycss/utilities-layout/margins.css` and if that does not exist it would look for `node_modules/superflycss/utilities-layout/margins/index.css`, and if that does not it exist it would thrown an error.

- `@import @superflycss/utilities-layout/margins/`

Would import `node_modules/superflycss/utilities-layout/margins/index.css` only.

The modules I'm producing have have the kitchen sink packaged in the directory `target/main/css/index.css`.  This exposes all the css utilities or components (Depending on what type of module it is).

The problem is, as with RxJS, this can be a very heavy file (For instance contain imports to all Google Fonts).

So I'm hoping that by following the RxJS approach the entire thing becomes more flexible and standardized by following the same rules that NodeJS require.resolv() algorithm uses.  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I think this is just a matter of requiring the "kitchen sink" or submodule relative to the root directory of the NPM package. Not sure what NPMs algorithm has anything to do with it.

Comment: Take a look at an installed copy of RxJS (i.e. inside of a node_modules folder), there's really nothing special going on.

Comment: Indeed - I updated my question to reflect your feedback - thanks.  I think it's as simple as what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostCSS does support importing submodules the same way RxJS does.  I added a pull request with test cases that illustrates how it's done [here](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import/pull/337).